# Why is there no entry to show/hide the field code in the (mouse) context menue for certain fields (word)?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

To show/hide the field code of a single field I usually use Shift+F9. But sometimes I need the context menu (for example when working with a tablet with a screen keyboard that does not have the "F"-Keys). I noticed that for certain codes, the context menue option "show/hide field code" is not available. For example when linking to a excel sheet using LINK, like in this case:

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "C:\\Folder123\\ExcelFileABC.xlsx" "Table1!Z8S8" }
```

Any ideas why or how to resolve this issue? Or maybe there is a workaround  like to show/hide it through the ribbon menu (in my case Word 2010).

I already know the workaround how to show all field codes in the document through the ribbon (file - options - advance options etc.) but this is A) very time consuming and B) can get very confusing when you use a few field right next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Create a macro like below and add it to the ribbon.

```
Sub ShowCode()
    Selection.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
End Sub
```

Then if you select a field (fields) and click this macro button it will show/hide field code(s). I tested this for your example and it works (no context menu - confirmed).

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say that I need a solution that is already implemented within word. I my case I won't have the option to add VBA-Code and configure the ribbon. It's a good idea though if the option is available.